# @font-face sin css?

Tags: html, css, web, formularios

Estoy intentando editar un formulario para acuity scheduling con html y quiero agregar mis propias fuentes pero el problema es que no me deja añadir css externo es posible hacerlo con el parámetro `style` y sucede lo mismo en roundcube cuando intento redactar un correo con texto enriquecido en el y también lo intente con el plano pero no funciona porque no lo procesa correctamente

Algo Así

```
<p style="@font-face{font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);} font-family:myFirstFont;">Hola</p>
```

Tampoco me permite con `@import`

`<p style="@import url('https5//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=slabo+27px');font-family: Slabo;">HOLA</p>`

Ni me permite hacerlos con las etiquetas `style`.

Miren lo que sucede

Antes de Guardar

```
<style>
@font-face{
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
</style>
```

Después de Guardar

```
<p>@font-face{</p>
<p>font-family: myFirstFont;</p>
<p>src: url(sansation_light.woff);</p>
<p>}</p>
```

No me deja añadir un código `html` normal solo fragmentos

```
<style>
@font-face{
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
</style>
```

Entonces que puedo hacer?

**PD:el RTF es tiny MCE**

Comment: desde el atributo style no se puede agregar una fuente de esa manera. la etiqueta style esta dentro de la seccion head?

Comment: no lo que pasa es que no puedo agregar un formato html normal

Comment: entonces habría que reformular la pregunta dando mas detalles para que te podamos ofrecer una solución a tu problema.

Comment: En primer lugar, ¿Estás seguro que **Acuity Scheduling** lo permite? y segundo ¿Has revisado la documentación de la página?

Comment: Esto parece un problema al usar un editor de texto enriquecido, que procesa tu texto como HTML. ¿Tienes la opción de poner el texto como texto plano en lugar de como texto enriquecido? ¿Qué editor RTF es? ¿Has probado a ponerlo todo en una línea?

Answer (score 0):

no estas usando nunca a la fuente, la estas agregando correctamente y luego la debes usar

debería ser

```
<p>Hola</p>
```

y en el css

```
<style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(sansation_light.woff);
    }

    p { font-family: "myFirstFont"; }
</style>
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la api de Google Fonts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: no funciona @Eddy

Comment: @Ger solo estas editando en solo texto, busca la opcion de html personalizado o custom html